# SSMS Temporary Files

Tags: file, ssms, temporary

I have SSMS SQL Express on my personal machine so I can improve my SQL writing. I have recently been getting a warning that my C drive space is very low. After running disk clean up, I’m still very low.

Are there temporary files created by SSMS when I run a query that are causing this? If so, where can I find them and safely delete them knowing that I’m not going to destroy my entire set up.

The backend inner workings of SSMS are not a strong point of mine so please forgive me if this question is rather basic. Thanks in advance for any advice given.

Thank you

Comment: SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) stores its temporary files in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\SSMS` though they tend to not be especially large; mine are a little over 100Kb

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.